# How to move focus to different edittext while scanning?

Tags: android, android-edittext, scanning, setfocus

I have two `EditText`. One `EditText` is for scanning and second one is for search purpose.
But when I do searching and try to do scanning then search `EditText` takes the focus of  scanning `EditText`.

How can I stop search `EditText` from taking the focus.

Answer (score 1):

You can focus any `EditText` whenever you want as,

```
yourEditText.requestFocus();
```

And you can also remove or clear focus from any `EditText` as,

```
yourEditText.clearFocus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a boolean variable isScanning:

```
Boolean isScanning = false;
```

Just before you start scanning set:

```
isScanning = true;
```

Put this code in `onCreate()`:

```
    txtScanning.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus && isScanning) {
                txtScanning.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    });
```

Change `txtScanning` to your EditText's id.

After you finish scanning, set

```
isScanning = false;
```